# C# customized resx with localization

Tags: c#, resources, resx

In C# resources can be retrieved with a given file name like

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("namespace.myresource",this.GetType().Assembly);
string someString = rm.GetString("GeneralError", culture);
```

With this, localization can be achieved by having the culture to the end of file. But I need to have it to customize to instance level also.

ex: myresource.instance1.resx, myresource.instance3.resx, myresource.instance1.fr-FR.resx,..etc.

But with the basic resourcemanager, this cannot be achieved. Is there any specific way to read the resources like this? (db approach is not suitable for the application)

Comment: what is instance in your case? Instance of what?

Comment: @Nino - its like a portal. I need customized wordings for each portal

Comment: check if you can use `ResXResourceSet` class for loading and reading custom resource files. With that approach you can specify name of resource file. Check out [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Nino you saved my life . It worked

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nino - Thanks for the help.

This can be sorted out as below

```
var rsxr = new ResXResourceReader("MyResource.resx");
rsxr.UseResXDataNodes = true;
foreach (DictionaryEntry dEntry in rsxr)
{
    var node = (ResXDataNode)dEntry.Value;
    if (node.FileRef == null)
    {
        var paramValue = node.GetValue((ITypeResolutionService) null);
    }
}
```